# C float initialization result is unexpected

Tags: c, floating-point, initialization

Visual Studio 2019 Community
float variable is not what I initialize it to.
I made it less precise in hopes of avoiding truncation.
Is this not "controllable"?

tried to force init to round in other ways

```
int main()
{
    // where did my 6 go?
    float b = 80.123456F;
    printf("b:[%f]\n", b);

    // rounds up
    float c = 80.1234569F;
    printf("c:[%f]\n", c);

    // rounds up
    float d = 80.1234561F;
    printf("d:[%f]\n", d);


    // appends a 1
    float e = 80.12345F;
    printf("e:[%f]\n", e);

    // prints what's initialized
    float f = 80.123451F;
    printf("f:[%f]\n", f);

    // prints what's initialized
    float g = 80.123459F;
    printf("g:[%f]\n", g);
}
```

```
b:[80.123459]
c:[80.123459]
d:[80.123459]
e:[80.123451]
f:[80.123451]
g:[80.123459]
```

I had started with the debugger and wrote this to meet SO reqs.
In my case, the debugger matched the prints

Comment: `printf` produces a text *representation* of the float value. Check the value in the debugger if you want to know what the CPU thinks the value is.

Comment: The exact value for `float b = 80.123456F;` is 80.1234588623046875.

Comment: You have a difference in the 8th significant digit, whereas `float` is only good for about 7. There are infinitely many real numbers in the range covered by `float` which has a finite storage of about 2^32 different values. So most real values have to be approximated to the nearest exact value which can be represented.

Comment: The largest IEEE 754 32 bit number strictly less than 80.1234588623046875 is 80.12345123291015625. There is no rounding magic that can get any float result between those two values.

Comment: How does one find the exact value ?

Comment: The [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) is a great tool to understand such kind of unexpected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floats are only accurate to at most 7 significant digits. Not 7 *decimal* digits. 80.123456F has 8 significant digits, so that isn't going to work.

While 80.12345 has only 7 significant digits, it actually ends up at around 80.1234512329101562. Which, as long as you're not trying to print more digits than it has, is OK. Unfortunately, %f always prints 6 digits after the decimal point. Which in this case, is one more than makes sense. You'd do slightly better with %g where you can specifiy number of significant digits instead.

Comment: How do you know it " ends up at around 80.1234512329101562"  if its actually that, how is it  "only 7 significant digits" ?  Thanks

Comment: @chup - Number of significant digits is specified by the `FLT_DECIMAL_DIG`, `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`, and `LDBL_DECIMAL_DIG` macros defined in `float.h`. This is the maximum number of digits that are *guaranteed* to be accurate representations for a given type (`float`, `double`, and `long double`, respectively), even though some specific values may offer more digits of precision.  The "actual" value can be deduced by looking at a binary representation of the value and adding up the bits manually.

Comment: 1/10 cannot be represented exactly in binary. Only fractions like 1/2, 1/4, ... 1/65536 (etc) can be. There is maths that'll show you what you can rely on, but the figures work out at 7 digits of precision for IEEE floating point values.

Comment: @TomTanner John Bode, thanks guys, thats what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- `printf` with the `%f` conversion specifier does its own rounding of floating-point values for display.  You can control how many digits following the decimal point are displayed by using a precision specifier: `printf( "%.8f\n", b );` will print up to 8 digits following the decimal point, and `printf( "%.16f\n", a);` will print 16.  Don't trust that displayed value, though, because...
- An infinite number of real values cannot fit into a finite number of bits, so most real values cannot be represented *exactly* - you get an approximation that's only good out to so many decimal digits.  Single-precision `float` types don't guarantee much more than 6 to 7 decimal digits of precision (that's not just the number of digits following the decimal point, that's *total number of digits*).  `double` gives you something like 10 to 11 digits.  If you need to represent values with many digits of precision (more than 12 or so), then you need go past native floating point types and use a third-party multiple precision library.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem may be to change data types. Even though `double` operates in the same way as `float`, approximating a large range of real numbers by a finite set of rationals, doubles are so close together that the rounding error is less likely to matter.

For example, the `float` values closest to the real number 80.123456 are 80.12345123291015625 and 80.1234588623046875. The `double` values closest to 80.123456 are 80.123456000000004451067070476710796356201171875 and 80.1234559999999902402123552747070789337158203125.

`float` does have its uses, in situations in which you are dealing with very large sets of very low precision numbers, but `double` is the more generally useful type. When getting a physical quantity into a program using `double`, the measurement error will exceed the rounding error.